# Javascript add MySQL data when checkbox is ticked

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am currently using this javscript and PHP code

```
<script>
function add(total)
{
    form2.thetotal.value = document.forms["form1" + total].total.value;
}
</script>

<form name="form2">
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" style="position:fixed; z-index:-999; background-color:#FFF;">
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" width="50%"><strong>Total: </strong><input type="text" name="thetotal" id="thetotal" size="20" value="0" /></td>
    <td colspan="2" width="50%"><strong>VAT:</strong> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%"><strong>Invoice Number</strong></td>
    <td width="35%"><strong>Company</strong></td>
    <td width="20%"><strong>Date</strong></td>
    <td width="20%"><strong>Total</strong></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<form name="form1">
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
<?php
$sql="SELECT * from billing_pdf_archive order by invoice_number ASC ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $counter++;
    $sql2="SELECT * from customer where sequence = '".$result["customer_sequence"]."' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);

    $sql3="SELECT * from reseller where sequence = '".$result["reseller_sequence"]."' ";
    $rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3);

    if($result["customer_sequence"] != '0')
    {
        $company = $result2["company"];
    }
    elseif($result["reseller_sequence"] != '0')
    {
        $company = '<strong>Reseller: </strong>'.$result3["company"];
    }

    $total = $result["total"];

    echo '<tr>
    <td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" onclick=\'add('.$total.');\' /></td>
    <td width="20%">'.$result["invoice_number"].'</td>
    <td width="35%">'.$company.'</td>
    <td width="20%">'.$result["datetime"].'</td>
    <td width="20%">&pound;'.$result["total"].'</td>
  </tr>';
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

so as you can see it is selecting from the MySQL database and i am trying to make it so when one of the checkboxes is ticked it adds the total into the "thetotal" text field (in form 2) but it is just leaving that box as zero - any ideas on what i could do?

Comment: Please don’t show server-side code, when you want to discuss a client-side problem. Show us the _real_ code the client receives.

Comment: whats the final verdict? will you mark the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it (assuming total is int and not float):

```
<script>
function add(total, this_chk_bx)
{
    //(if its float, use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`)

    if(this_chk_bx.checked==true){
    //add if its checked
    var tot_1 = parseInt(form2.thetotal.value);
    form2.thetotal.value = tot_1+parseInt(total);
    }
    else{
    //subtract if its unchecked
    }
}
</script>
```

.

in your php, you have to send the checkbox like this:
`onclick=\'add('.$total.', this);\'`

.

Comment: ah perfect - works great - how about if i tick multiple boxes, can it add them all together? with this code it is just displaying the most recently checked row total?

Comment: excellent - do you know how i would run a function when the box is unchecked as this only runs when the box is checked?

Comment: Basically, as you check the multiple fields 1 by 1, it will simply sum them all. It will take the first 'total' and add it to `form2.thetotal`. Then when you click on next add total checkbox, it will add the last total (present at form2.thetotal) with new total.

Comment: I have tried this javascript code which does work but, when i check 2 boxes it adds up correctly then when i uncheck one it puts the right amount but makes it a minus number? http://jsfiddle.net/3pbtK/

Comment: check now at http://jsfiddle.net/3pbtK/2/. I have added this `if(tot_1>=parseFloat(total)){}` condition

Comment: still got the same issue with the minus :/

Comment: did you re arrange the minus line? `form2.thetotal.value = tot_1-parseFloat(total);`

Comment: otherwise, you may have to forcibly absolute it with `Math.abs()` function

Comment: i just copied what you done on the fiddle, i have just checked again and maybe it just didnt refresh properly. it seems to put in long numbers when i uncheck all boxes (1.1368683772161603e-13) there are some totals that aren't round numbers (e.g: 100.43)

Comment: try `Math.round()` function. like `form2.thetotal.value = Math.round(tot_1-parseFloat(total));`

Comment: sorry - what is that function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27960/discussion-between-raheel-hasan-and-charliejsford)

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the total field for form 1, then it raised javascript error, it wont work.
Check it out

```
                            <script>
            function add(total)
            {
                form2.thetotal.value =  total + parseFloat(document.form1.formtotal.value);
            }
            </script>


            <form name="form1">

            <!-- replace field name formtotal with anything that you want-->
            <!-- replace field value with anything that you get from your mysql result-->
            <input type="text" name="formtotal" id="formtotal" value="10" />
            </form>
```